# How does lifetime rule stops multiple mutable borrow?

Tags: rust

I have been reading this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1215) which shows a trivial example of how multiple mutable borrows can throw this error `"cannot borrow point as mutable more than once at a time"`:

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64
}

impl Point {
    pub fn x_mut(&mut self) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.x
    }

    pub fn y_mut(&mut self) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.y
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut point = Point { x: 1.0, y: 2.0 };
    let x_mut = point.x_mut();
    let y_mut = point.y_mut();

    *x_mut *= 2.0;
    *y_mut *= 2.0;
}
```

But then came the part which confused me.

> The lifetime elision rules make it pretty clear why this happens:
> `x_mut()` returns a mutable borrow that has to live at least as long as
> the mutable borrow of `self`

How does the fact that the mutable borrow should exist as long `self` explain this error?

Comment: Variable `x_mut` has to exit scope (older Rust) or stop being used (newer non-lexical lifetimes Rust) in order for the mutable borrow of `point` to be finished.  As long as one mutable borrow is active, a second one (point for variable `y_mut`) cannot be established.  The method signatures say `&mut self`, but in context of `main`, that self refers to `point`.

Answer (score 3):

Variable `x_mut` has to exit scope (older Rust) or stop being used (newer non-lexical lifetimes Rust) in order for the mutable borrow of `point` to be finished.  As long as one mutable borrow is active, a second one (point for variable `y_mut`) cannot be established.  The method signatures say `&mut self`, but in context of `main`, that self refers to `point`.

```
         |
 +->  18 |     let x_mut = point.x_mut();
 |       |                 ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
 |    19 |     let y_mut = point.y_mut();
 |       |                 ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
 |    20 | 
 +->  21 |     *x_mut *= 2.0;
         |     ------------- first borrow later used here
```

The extent of the first borrow is from 18 thru 21, and, you cannot have another mutable borrow of `point` within that range.  So 19 is flagged as an error.  line 19's code can happily occur after line 21, so the following is legal:

```
fn main() {
    let mut point = Point { x: 1.0, y: 2.0 };

    let x_mut = point.x_mut();
    *x_mut *= 2.0;

    let y_mut = point.y_mut();
    *y_mut *= 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Two mutable reference to disjoint fields can coexist. Thats what he is trying to achieve in this. But what i dont understand is how the lifetime of  ``self`` related to this as he suggests and the mock solution to this problem.

Comment: The code you asked about tells the borrow checker that you want to make a mutable borrow of `point` so that the mutable borrowed return value of `.x_mut()` can live for as long as the code in `main` needs it.  Thus, the invocation of `point.x_mut()` establishes a borrow of `point` that the compiler takes to live as long as the return result lives.  Since the borrowed return result lives for a time, the mutable borrow of `point` is taken to live that long as well.  Thus, a second mutable borrow of point for the call to `point.y_mut()` is not possible within the window of the first such borrow.

Comment: As far as overlapping borrows of disjoint fields, it is possible and a good question: it easy to do directly, but it is the encapsulation into methods that makes it tricky; suggest you (search for that and/or) ask it directly in a separate question.  For example, see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8fc6f2b4c1e02b0cf884264a2f8d060) where we borrow both x and y mutably but in a single method, which uses only one mutable borrow of `point`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your intuition is correct in that the lifetime elision rules don't really explain this. Part of the problem is that the example contains some red herrings. For instance you could comment out:

```
*y_mut *= 2.0;
```

and still get the error. Also you don't need to actually use `x_mut` as mutable to get the error. This simpler version illustrates the same problem:

```
fn main() {
    let mut point = Point { x: 1.0, y: 2.0 };
    let x_mut = point.x_mut();
    let y_mut = point.y_mut();

    println!("x_mut = {}", x_mut);
}
```

If you comment out the `y_mut` line or even if you move that line after the call to `println!()` it works fine. So it's just like you said at the start, you can't have multiple mutable references to `point` at the same time.

Note that I'm referring only to your post and not the discussion you linked to which I haven't read.